# Generate resume(bio-data) in word document format from c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Could you explain the way of generate resume(bio-data) in word document format from c#?

modules are:
1. input the required values from user using form design.
2. And store into database.
3. by clicking download button to generate a resume with aligned format.

pls help me the steps for generate and with perfect alignment format.

using c#..

Comment: what is the perfect alignment format?

Comment: perfect alignment nothing but auto align.

Answer (score 0):

you can user [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for Microsoft word automation. But I personally suggest to use [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for office application automation. Please read their documentation before writing codes. There are a couple number of third party plugin available in market.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to do step 1 and 2 so I only talk about step 3:

In C# just use  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word(make a reference to it,from your main project)

Then start the Word Macro recorder and then do the alignments manually (in word directly).

After that, stop the Excel's macro recorder and edit the recorded macro. You will see the VBA code used to do the Word page formating.

The objects, properties and methods which are needed in C#, are "Exactly" same as those you see in the VBA Macro. So basically all you need is to copy them from VBA to the C# code.